# SMS messages never delivered if target phone is off-network

Tags: sms

I have a Samsung GT-I5500 (Europa) running Android 2.1.

Sending an SMS message to an off-phone will result in a notification saying 'message not sent'

It is never delivered even after the target phone is turned back on.

Message should be stored on network until it expires or is delivered.

I have eliminated network causes by trying the SIM in a non Android phone, which works as it should do.

I also tried a different network SIM in the phone, same problem.

I suspect the SMS 'message validity' field but cannot find a way to access it.

Anyone experienced this? Are there any solutions?

Comment: Have you contacted your carrier?  Have you brought your phone in to be replaced under warranty?  This sounds like your device isn't playing nice with the network to me, or vice versa.

Comment: FWIW this never happens with Google Voice.

Comment: Hmm, could [Handcent](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) possibly get around this?

Comment: Handcent does not get round it. Also I'd prefer to solve the problem, rather than get round it.

Comment: Yeah I contacted Orange. It was a call centre in India or somewhere. They really couldn't give a monkeys. And cut me off when they realised it was a difficult question (after wasting my time and money taking pointless details). I didn't bother calling back.

Comment: I was going to go back to the shop, but then I realised what would probably happen... I would attempt to demonstrate the problem.. and it wouldn't happen. This led me to the fix, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a lot of research around this issue, I deleted the relevant contact, and all the conversations, and after adding the contact again, everything worked OK.

I believe it has something to do with having multiple copies of the same number in the messaging system. ie +447891.... 07891..... 447891... etc I might be completely wrong about this. But it definitely works now, on all 3 messaging apps that I have tried.

Comment: Be sure to mark yourself as the answer.

Comment: Well since I'm not quite sure if its the right answer, wouldnt it be better if I let it just sit there for a while? Could I go back on that action and choose a different answer later? My solution certainly seems to have cured it, but the fact remains that this should never happen in the first place. If there is a remedy for that, that would be the best answer.